# How to convert asp.net json date format to DD-MM in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, date-formatting

Hi i need help in converting data-time format. I'm using Cordova and JqueryMobile, my web services are in asp.net. In response of my Ajax call i get date in the format below.

```
"/Date(1425935535000+0000)/"
```

I need to convert it to DD-MMM format (i.e 13-Mar ) what utility i use to convert it. any plugin is appreciated. i have also tried [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/) but it fails
here is what i have done so far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/gjtkvrsy/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var Months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
var dt = new Date(1425935535000+0000);

var sFinalDate = dt.getDate() + " " + Months[dt.getMonth()]
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ed3qavuj/